# Duvidas sobre HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá,
Estou começando agora e estou com a seguinte duvida:
Ao montar uma pagina com HTML e CSS, eu adicionei os ícones para acesso as minha redes sociais (exemplo: Instagram, LinkedIn, etc..) mas só adicionei a imagem. Como faço para transformar essa imagem do ícone (exemplo: Instagram) em um um link aonde eu possa clicar e ser direcionado para a página?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda e atenção.
Abraço!

Comment: Edita sua pergunta com seu código, assim fica mais facil de te dar uma resposta que te atenda

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a tag `<a>` com um `href` contendo o link para sua página, dessa forma:

```
  <a href="fb.com/seu_perfil">
     <img src="seu_icone_aqui">
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir a sua tag de imagem dentro de uma tag de hiperlink, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<a><img /><a/>
```